# Input stream with grpc-wiremock leads to an exception

Tags: grpc, wiremock

Hello I try to make setup with [grpc-wiremock](https://github.com/Adven27/grpc-wiremock), everything works great except when my rpc method has a stream in input. I didn't manage to make it work in this case.

I use the following simple proto file (placed in ${PWD}/proto_test/dev/test/streams.proto):

```
syntax = "proto3";

package dev.test;

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

service TestStreamService {
  rpc testInputStream(stream TestStreamValue) returns (google.protobuf.Empty);
  rpc testOutputStream(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (stream TestStreamValue);
  rpc testBidirStream(stream TestStreamValue) returns (stream TestStreamValue);
}

message TestStreamValue {
  int32 value = 1;
}
```

And the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM adven27/grpc-wiremock

COPY ./proto_test/dev/test /proto/dev/test

RUN gradle compileJava --info --stacktrace
```

After building and running this docker (`docker image build -t protogrpc-poc-wiremock -f docker/Dockerfile.grpc_wiremock . && docker container run -p 8888:8888 -p 50000:50000 protogrpc-poc-wiremock`), I call the stub API for output stream

```
:~$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8888/__admin/mappings   -d '{
    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/TestStreamService/testOutputStream"
    },
    "response": {
        "fixedDelayMilliseconds": 1000,
        "headers": {"streamSize": "5" },
        "jsonBody": {
            "value": "{{request.headers.streamCursor}}"
        }
    }
}'
```

And call the grpc method testOutputStream which returns the expected 5 values streaming:

```
:~$ grpcurl -plaintext localhost:50000 dev.test.TestStreamService.testOutputStream
{
  "value": 1
}
{
  "value": 2
}
{
  "value": 3
}
{
  "value": 4
}
{
  "value": 5
}
```

When I do the same with testInputStream:

```
:~$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8888/__admin/mappings   -d '{
    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/TestStreamService/testInputStream"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200
    }
}'
```

I got an exception:

```
:~$ grpcurl -plaintext -d '{"value":2}{"value": 5}' localhost:50000 dev.test.TestStreamService.testInputStreamm
ERROR:
  Code: Unknown
  Message:
```

And the following stack trace in grpc-wiremock side:

```
2022-11-21 07:25:14.485 ERROR 198 --- [ault-executor-1] io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor     : Exception while executing runnable io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl$1HandleServerCall@17e05f9e

java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl$1HandleServerCall.runInternal(ServerImpl.java:619) ~[grpc-core-1.44.1.jar:1.44.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl$1HandleServerCall.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:603) ~[grpc-core-1.44.1.jar:1.44.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[grpc-core-1.44.1.jar:1.44.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133) ~[grpc-core-1.44.1.jar:1.44.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at io.adven.grpc.wiremock.Translator$WireMockTranslator.redirect(Translator.java:33) ~[main/:na]
    at io.adven.grpc.wiremock.Translator$WireMockTranslator.redirectDevTestTestStreamService(Translator.java:59) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:624) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:72) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at io.adven.grpc.wiremock.Translator$DevTestTestStreamService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$32b9d9e2.testInputStream(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at dev.test.TestStreamServiceGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(TestStreamServiceGrpc.java:320) ~[main/:na]
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$StreamingServerCallHandler.startCall(ServerCalls.java:235) ~[grpc-stub-1.44.1.jar:1.44.1]
    at io.grpc.Contexts.interceptCall(Contexts.java:52) ~[grpc-api-1.44.1.jar:1.44.1]
    at io.adven.grpc.wiremock.HeaderPropagationInterceptor.interceptCall(HeaderPropagationInterceptor.java:27) ~[main/:na]
    at io.grpc.ServerInterceptors$InterceptCallHandler.startCall(ServerInterceptors.java:244) ~[grpc-api-1.44.1.jar:1.44.1]
    at io.adven.grpc.wiremock.ExceptionHandler.interceptCall(ExceptionHandler.java:22) ~[main/:na]
    at io.grpc.ServerInterceptors$InterceptCallHandler.startCall(ServerInterceptors.java:244) ~[grpc-api-1.44.1.jar:1.44.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl.startWrappedCall(ServerImpl.java:703) ~[grpc-core-1.44.1.jar:1.44.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl.access$2200(ServerImpl.java:406) ~[grpc-core-1.44.1.jar:1.44.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerTransportListenerImpl$1HandleServerCall.runInternal(ServerImpl.java:615) ~[grpc-core-1.44.1.jar:1.44.1]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

I would like to open an issue in the github project but it is now in read-only (which is worrying me a bit, I must admit).
Is anybody managed to make grpc input stream call with grpc-wiremock ?